# Not able to use orderBy in Laravel query with distinct

Tags: laravel, postgresql, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder, laravel-10

Hi I am using Laravel 10 .
My issue is not able to use orderby() with distinct().

I am using PostgreSQL as database.
When I tried Group_by , I am getting repeated results. I have tried many solutions found here, but nothing works for me.

My Query

```
$property = DB::table('properties')
            ->leftjoin('property_sub_types', 'property_sub_types.id', '=', 'properties.property_sub_type')
            ->leftjoin('property_images', 'properties.id', '=', 'property_images.property_id')
            ->leftjoin('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'properties.city')
            ->select('properties.name as proName', 'properties.id as pro_id', 'properties.city', 'properties.street', 'property_sub_types.name as subName', 'property_images.image as imgName','cities.name as ctyName','properties.reserve_price','properties.description','properties.possession','properties.ownership','properties.auction_start_date','properties.contact_manager','properties.contact_number', 'properties.updated_at')
            ->where('properties.property_status', 4)
            ->where('properties.status', 1)
            ->where('property_sub_types.status', 1)
            ->orderBy('properties.updated_at')
            ->distinct('properties.id')
            ->paginate(30);
```

Error showing as

> SQLSTATE[42P10]: Invalid column reference: 7 ERROR: SELECT DISTINCT ON
> expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions LINE 1: select
> distinct on ("properties"."id")

Comment: You will need to add orderBy('properties.id') also.

Comment: @SabinChacko `->orderBy('properties.id')
            ->orderBy('properties.updated_at')` I have added this and getting results also but, results orderby properties.id not by updated_at

Comment: You haven't explained very clearly what you want to do.  Maybe you want to use `distinct()` with no argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply distinct on **name** column of **properties** table to get distinct properties value. I hope this can be helpful.